# using openpyxl to update certain columns in a complex spreadsheet

Tags: openpyxl

Hi I have a pretty complex spreadsheet and I need to update "ONLY" certain part of its contents.

I tried openpyxl, which works ok except all the pivot tables, styles and formulas are lost, after save the workbook. Is there a way to get around that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check which version of openpyxl you have installed. Support for Pivot Tables was only added in version 2.5.0-a1 (2017-05-30), and that only supported one Pivot Table until version 2.5.0-b2 (2018-01-19). See [changelog](http://openpyxl.readthedocs.io/en/default/changes.html).

Alternatives: Simplify, xlwings, content protection, and **win32com** (most likely).

If you are using 2.5 and it doesn't work, you'll probably have to simplify your spreadsheet if you want to continue to use openpyxl. E.g. split it into a source and output file, and use python to update the source file.

You could try running [xlwings](https://www.xlwings.org/) to host the Python code inside of the spreadsheet itself.

Another possible solution would be to lock the contents - turn on protection - for all except the sections you plan to update. This is unlikely to work as python is changing the contents directly, but it may respect the lock.

Finally, the result most likely to work. Drive the changes through the win32com module. I think this, unlike openpyxl, requires Excel to be installed as it is using Excel's functionality to make the changes. Examples of usage are [here](http://pythonexcels.com/python-excel-mini-cookbook/) and [here](http://pythonexcels.com/basic-excel-driving-with-python/).

A brief example (taken from [here](http://pythonexcels.com/python-excel-mini-cookbook/)):

```
import win32com.client as win32
excel = win32.gencache.EnsureDispatch('Excel.Application')
wb = excel.Workbooks.Add()
ws = wb.Worksheets("Sheet1")
ws.Cells(1,1).Value = "Cell A1"
ws.Cells(1,1).Offset(2,4).Value = "Cell D2"
ws.Range("A2").Value = "Cell A2"
ws.Range("A3:B4").Value = "A3:B4"
ws.Range("A6:B7,A9:B10").Value = "A6:B7,A9:B10"
wb.SaveAs('ranges_and_offsets.xlsx')
excel.Application.Quit()
```